# Java - use searchbar on given website

Tags: java

Let me just start by saying that this is a soft question.

I am rather new to application development, and thus why I'm asking a question without presenting you with any actual code. I know the basics of `Java` coding, and I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me on the following topic:

Say I have an external website, Craigslist, or some other site that allows me to search through products/services/results manually by typing a query into a searchbox somewhere on the page. The trouble is, that there is no API for this site for me to use.

However I do know that `http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=QUERYHERE&sort=rel` points me to a list of results, where `QUERYHERE` is replaced by what I'm looking for.

What I'm wondering here is: is it possible to store these results in an `Array` (or `List` or some form of `Collection`) in `Java`?

Is there perhaps some library or external tool that can allow me to specify a query to search for, have it paste it in to a search-link, perform the search, and fill an `Array` with the results?

Or is what I am describing impossible without an API?

Comment: `Or is what I am describing impossible without an API?` - True. Thats not possible. You never know what the search results yield. It could be html, json, xml or some other format. So each search hit will be specific to that website response and it might break any time they change the response

Comment: I guess you can't do it without the [**java API**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)

Comment: There is no *general* solution to this problem. What you (seemingly) want to do is known as [scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping#Web_scraping), and there are a number of tools which can help you with that (but tool recommendation questions are not on topic for Stack Overflow). You should expand on your question to explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish and *what you have tried*, as any solution will depend on what you are trying to do and what site you are trying to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends, if the query website accepts returning the result as XML or JSON (usually with a .xml or .json at the end of url) you can parse it easily with DOM for XML on Java or download and use the JSONLibrary to parse a JSON.

Otherwise you will receive a HTML that is the page that a user would see in a browser, then you can try parse it as a XML but you will have a lot of work to map all fields in the HTML to get the list as you want.